# #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 13.570 seconds)>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am debugging the each and every line of the code. Is this might be the reason for the occurrence of this error? If so then how can I debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have too many open connections to the database.

You can wrap your code in the block which closes the connection automatically.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  # your code
end
```